# Beveling tight corners results in shading errors

Tags: modeling, error, bevel

I'm trying to apply a bevel to a tight corner area of a model:

[image]

Unfortunately, no matter how I try to do this, I end up with shading errors in the corners.

[image][image]

I'm using smooth shading, with auto-smooth (46º). I've tried applying the weighted normal modifier (doesn't help) and I've tried adding addition loops (didn't help). Is there a way to fix this issue? It's quite visible, even from a distance.

Update:

I'm attaching the source file here. [image]

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hi :). The angle is probably over 46°, adding more bevel segments should help, right?

Comment: You have bad topology there. N-gons and non planar quads. Get rid of that and it should start behaving.

Comment: I added the source .blend file for anyone interested in taking a look. @radoo -- there are a couple non-planar quads in the bridge of the handle, but even if I planar-ize them, the bevel problem persists. Adding more bevel segments does help, but I have to add at least 4-5 additional ones, which seems excessive.

Comment: True, The topology needs to be better and good enough to give space for the bevel effect to connect the shape smoothly, This is common you should implement a good topology instead of directly using Ctrl+B for beveling them automatically if you want good results.

Comment: Also dont forget to invert normals. =)

Comment: The model also has inverted faces, loose geometry and overlapping vertices.

Comment: The loose faces are part of the inner glass bulb, and shouldn't be an issue. The overlapping verts were not in the region, but I've fixed those (and the inverted faces). It still doesn't resolve the issue with shading around the area being beveled. Any other things I can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inverted face normals as seen in red. Select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd> and go to object menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.

[image]

Also your geometry is non-manifold, you have internal faces which is invalid. Check this thread: [What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)

[image]

Comment: oh I just realized they aren't connected when i pressed `L` on the oblong body so i guess that's ok.

Comment: thanks. I fixed the flipped normals, but it doesn't change the shading problem when bridging the handles to the main body. What I'm finding is that "bridge edge loops" doesn't really do a good job creating a topologically sound transition (in this case). Is there a different modeling technique I could use to bridge the handles/body mesh parts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick sketch with a better topology ( sorry, I don't have much time).
[image]

Rules of thumb:

- check you mesh regularly for errors (overlaps, inverted faces, detached parts)
- use reflective materials for curvature checks
- if non-planar, n-gons are poison (as are quads, if too stretched)
- even geometry is good topology
- replace your loops (aka retopo on the fly)
  There are more but I gotta go

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look at what you did there.